# How to correctly import user defined classes in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, nrepl

I am using Leiningen and Clojure and for the life of me I can't understand why Clojure makes it so difficult just to import namespaces correctly. This is the following error

This is what I have in my `core.clj` file:

```
; namespace macro
(ns animals.core
  (:require animals.animal)
  (:use animals.animal)
  (:import (animals.animal Dog))
  (:import (animals.animal Human))
  (:import (animals.animal Arthropod))
  (:import (animals.animal Insect)))

; make-animals will create a vector of animal objects
(defn make-animals []
  (conj []
        (Dog. "Terrier" "Canis lupis familiaris")
        (Human. "Human" "Homo sapiens")
        (Arthropod. "Brown Recluse" "Loxosceles reclusa")
        (Insect. "Fire Ant" "Solenopsis conjurata")))

; print-animals will print all the animal objects
(defn print-animals [animals]
  (doseq [animal animals]
    (println animal)))

; move-animals will call the move action on each animal
(defn move-animals [animals]
  (doseq [animal animals]
    (animals.animal/move animal)))

; entry to main program
(defn -main [& args]
  (let [animals make-animals]
    (do
      (println "Welcome to Animals!")
      (println "-------------------")
      (print-animals animals))))
```

Then, at the REPL, I enter the following (in the src/ directory of the `lein` project):

```
user> (require 'animals.core)
nil
user> (animals.core/-main)
ClassNotFoundException animals.core  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

Okay... what? Why?

For reference, here is my file `animal.clj` also in the `animals` directory:

```
(ns animals.animal)

(defprotocol Animal
  "A simple protocol for animal behaviors."
  (move [this] "Method to move."))

(defrecord Dog [name species]
  Animal
  (move [this] (str "The " (:name this) " walks on all fours.")))

(defrecord Human [name species]
  Animal
  (move [this] (str "The " (:name this) " walks on two legs.")))

(defrecord Arthropod [name species]
  Animal
  (move [this] (str "The " (:name this) " walks on eight legs.")))

(defrecord Insect [name species]
  Animal
  (move [this] (str "The " (:name this) " walks on six legs.")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code pasted into a fresh Leiningen project, I get a different error due to a typo in `-main`: `(let [animals make-animals] ...)` should be `(let [animals (make-animals)] ...)`. With this change, it all works fine:

```
user=> (require 'animals.core)
nil
user=> (animals.core/-main)
Welcome to Animals!
-------------------
#animals.animal.Dog{:name Terrier, :species Canis lupis familiaris}
#animals.animal.Human{:name Human, :species Homo sapiens}
#animals.animal.Arthropod{:name Brown Recluse, :species Loxosceles reclusa}
#animals.animal.Insect{:name Fire Ant, :species Solenopsis conjurata}
nil
```

Incidentally, it doesn't matter where exactly you invoke `lein repl` from as long as it's somewhere inside the project directory.

I'd venture a guess that there was something the matter with your namespace when you first tried to `require` it and now it won't load due to some namespace loading state in your REPL. You might want to try `(require :reload 'animals.core)` and if that doesn't work, restart your REPL. (You could also paste your entire REPL interaction up to the `ClassNotFoundException` somewhere if you run into it again.)

Also, about your `ns` form:

1. You shouldn't both `:require` and `:use` the same namespace; `:use` already `:require`s it.
2. It's more usual to use a single `:import` clause (in fact, a single clause per clause type); for example,

   ```
   (:import (animals.animal Dog Human Arthropod Insect))
   ```

   It's purely a matter of style in Clojure, but in ClojureScript it is in fact required by the language.

Comment: On another note, you don't even need to import the classes if you're already requiring the namespace.  Each record has 2 additional functions defined for it which are the the records name with the a prefix.  `->Record` behaves like the constructor, but is a function.  `map->Record` takes an attribute map.  This can allow you to use, for example, `(animals.core/->Dog "Terrier" "Canis lupis familiaris")` and will probably make your code more portable across Clojure implementations.